# Find and replace a word in several text files with Java scanner and printwriter

Tags: java

Im trying to write a JSP to read the file using scanner and replace string. Below is what i'm trying. 
I'm able to find the string using scanner but it doesn't write to the file. The file is always empty. I would like to recursively search files in folders and replace a matching string. Your help is appreciated.

```
<%      

            out.println("File Details <br>");

                String resp = single("C:/Users/path");
                out.println(resp);


        %>
        <%!

                public static ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
                public static String single(String URL) {
                    System.out.println(URL);
                String respStr="";
                fileList.clear();
                java.io.File file;

                java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(URL);
                String[] list = dir.list();


                for (String filepath :  readDirectoryContents(dir,fileList)) {

                    try {   
                        Path path = Paths.get(filepath);
                        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

                        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
                        String searchStr = "searchtext";
                        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filepath, "UTF-8");
                        while(scan.hasNext()){

                            String line = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().toString();

                            if(line.contains(searchStr)){

                                content = content.replaceAll("searchtext", "replacetext");


                                respStr += filepath;
                                writer.println(line);
                                writer.printf("pi is %.3f\n", 3.1415926);
                            }


                        }

                        writer.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { 
                         respStr += filepath;
                         continue;
                    }

                }
                return respStr;

        }

        public static ArrayList<String> readDirectoryContents(File dir,ArrayList<String> fileList) {
            try {
                File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        readDirectoryContents(file,fileList);
                    } else {                            
                        fileList.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
                    }
                }                   
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            return fileList;
        }



%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
<%      

        out.println("File Details <br>");

            String resp = single("C:/Users/path");
            out.println(resp);


    %>
    <%!

            public static ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
            public static String single(String URL) {
                System.out.println(URL);
            String respStr="";
            fileList.clear();
            java.io.File file;

            java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(URL);
            String[] list = dir.list();


            for (String filepath :  readDirectoryContents(dir,fileList)) {

                try {   
                    Path path = Paths.get(filepath);
                    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

                    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
                    String searchStr = "searchtext";
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filepath, "UTF-8");

                        if(content.contains(searchStr)){

                            content = content.replaceAll("searchtext","replacetext");


                            respStr += filepath;

                           // writer.printf("pi is %.3f\n", 3.1415926);
                        }


                    writer.println(content);

                    writer.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { 
                     respStr += filepath;
                     continue;
                }

            }
            return respStr;

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> readDirectoryContents(File dir,ArrayList<String> fileList) {
        try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    readDirectoryContents(file,fileList);
                } else {                            
                    fileList.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
                }
            }                   
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileList;
    }
%>
```